# Can I use the “Host” directive in robots.txt?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Searching for specific information on the `robots.txt`, I stumbled upon a [Yandex help page](http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml#host)<sup>‡</sup> on this topic. It suggests that I could use the `Host` directive to tell crawlers my preferred mirror domain:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /dir/
Host: www.example.com
```

Also, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Host) states that Google too understands the `Host` directive, but there wasn’t much (i.e. none) information.

At [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/), I didn’t find anything on `Host` (or `Crawl-delay` as stated on Wikipedia).

1. Is it encouraged to use the `Host` directive at all?
2. Are there any resources at Google on this `robots.txt` specific?
3. How is compatibility with other crawlers?

<sup>‡</sup> *At least since the beginning of 2021, the linked entry does not deal with the directive in question any longer.*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: It’s about a technical aspect of hostnames and robots.txt, and it’s tagged “seo” and “robots.txt”. How does it appear off-topic?

Comment: If anyone is looking for Yandex host directive spec, here's a link: https://web.archive.org/web/20190102064128/https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html#format) says:

> Unrecognised headers are ignored.

They call it "headers" but this term is not defined anywhere. But as it’s mentioned in the section about the format, and in the same paragraph as `User-agent` and `Disallow`, it seems safe to assume that "headers" means "field names".

So yes, you can use `Host` or *any* other field name.

- Robots.txt parsers that support such fields, well, support them.
- Robots.txt parsers that don’t support such fields must ignore them.

But keep in mind: As they are not specified by the robots.txt project, you can’t be sure that different parsers support this field in the same way. So you’d have to check every supporting parser manually.

Comment: So `Host` is someone else’s addendum to the robots exclusion standard, as it’s not defined at robotstxt.org‽

Comment: @dakab: Yes, the `Host` field is not specified in the original robots.txt specification.

Answer (score 2):

Google does not support `Host:` in `robots.txt` file, so it would be better if you avoid using it.

Here is a screenshot from Google Search Console's `robots.txt` testing tool that shows that Googlebot doesn't recognize `Host:` rules:

[image]