# What are the rules for the robots.txt file?

Tags: robots.txt

I'm trying to build a robots.txt parser, and I got stuck on a simple point on my mind: What are the rules for the robots.txt file?

I start to search it, and on [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html%20%22robotstxt.org) I found a [document](http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt) from 1996 that define some rules for the robots.txt file. This document define clearly all the rules for the *User-agent*, *Allow* and *Disallow*.

Looking for some examples of robots.txt I found tags, like *Sitemap* and *Host*.

I kept looking for it and I found this [document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) on wikipedia. Explaining some extra tags.

But my point is, since I can't trust that much on Wikipedia and the Web Crawler technology is in constant development, creating new rules for the robots.txt file, is there a place that I can find every rule that can be defined on a robots.txt file?

Comment: What are you intending to do once you parse the file? Are you implementing a web crawler? Doing something else with it?

Comment: I'm planning to do a simple web crawler. To fetch an unique kind of content, but first I want to implement the robots.

Comment: I see. For something like that, you really only need "User-Agent", "Disallow", "X-Robots-Meta", and "<meta name="robots">". The other options are rather uncommon and apply to more advanced use cases (e.g. explicitly giving a crawl rate really only makes sense when you have a crawler that is regularly crawling the same website at very frequent intervals and has far greater capacity to crawl websites than most websites have to receive traffic from the crawler).

Comment: I know that I actually don't need it. But as I couldn't find a source that give me all the information about robots.txt, I would like to know if anyone else knows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html**](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) is the official/original robots.txt specification.¹

It defines the fields `User-agent` and `Disallow`, and it specifies that [clients must ignore unknown fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22031453/1591669). This allows others to create extensions (like, for example, the [`Sitemap` field defined by the Sitemaps protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_robots)).

There is no registry (so there is the risk of name collisions) and there is no standards organization responsible for collecting all extensions.

In 2008, Google ([their announcement](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2008/06/improving-on-robots-exclusion-protocol.html)), Microsoft², and Yahoo!³ ([their announcement](http://www.ysearchblog.com/2008/06/03/one-standard-fits-all-robots-exclusion-protocol-for-yahoo-google-and-microsoft/)) came together and agreed on a set of features they would support (note that they introduced reserved characters for `Disallow` values, while in the original spec, all characters would be interpreted literally).
However, this only documents *their* interpretation (for their bots); it’s not some kind of specification which other bots would have to follow. But checking their documentation (e.g., [from Bing](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-create-a-robots-txt-file-cb7c31ec), [from Google Search](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596), [from Yandex](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml)) can give you ideas what’s out there.

---

¹ http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt is a first draft for an RFC, but as far as I know this was never committed/published.

² Their announcement [seems to be 404](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/?p=8303).

³ Originally, their announcement seems to have been at http://www.ysearchblog.com/archives/000587.html, but that’s 404 now.

Comment: So, there is no official source. But know the documentation of the biggest crawlers can give an idea of what is happening in the moment. Thank @unor for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most official thing you will find is: http://www.robotstxt.org

But I think with respect to robots.txt it is much more important what actually works / is really used in practice -- not what someone wrote in some specification.

A good starting point for that would be Googles robots.txt information page and their online checker: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?rd=1 (as is also recommended at http://www.robotstxt.org/checker.html )

Comment: I know that is more important what actually works. But where I can look for updates to know if there is a new tag. As the tag Sitemap that I never heard before, seems to be a powerful "feature", how can I know if another "feature" of robots.txt is currently used?